# Will my motherboard be compatible with the Samsung 850 EVO 500GB 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD (MZ-75E500B/AM)?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata

I'm new to computers and was wondering If this Samsung SSD will be compatible with my current motherboard.

MotherBoard Model: GA-78LMT-USB3 6.0

Graphics Card: GTX 1060

CPU: Intel Core i5-8400

And the SSD of Question is the Samsung 850 EVO 500GB 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD (MZ-75E500B/AM)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The GA-78LMT-USB3 motherboard is a socket AM3+ motherboard. Are you sure this is the board you own? It's not compatible with the i5-8400 you listed.

Comment: SSD's are just as compatible as any spinning hard drive on any PC.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Your motherboard is not compatible with the processor you have indicated.

Answer (score -2):

The motherboard is not the important factor here, since it doesn't have any
in-built SATA III ports that are required for the disk.

To add SATA III you need a SATA III PCI-Express card like this
[random example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IDNSUNO)
(this is not a recommendation).

You have not mentioned if your computer already has such a PCI card.
If not, you will need to add it, after verifying that it has a free
suitable PCI slot.

---

In answer to a comment by @Moab: This motherboard only has SATA II connectors,
not SATA III. It will be a pity to use Samsung 850 EVO with SATA II
(if it will even work).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and is there an easy way to check if my computer has a free PCI slot?

Comment: Opening it up and looking is the best way.

Comment: @Moab: Only SATA II. See my addition to the answer. Image taken from your link.

Comment: SATA III is backwards compatible. However, the Intel processor, isn’t compatible with the motherboard.

Comment: IMO, this is a bad answer. Even if the user mistook the "8400" as the i5, and instead meant the AMD Phenom 8400, that's an AM2+ socket, not an AM3+ socket, which the reported motherboard uses. Also, I very highly doubt a computer with a GTX 1060 wouldn't have SATA3, let alone a modern i5-8400.

Comment: The answer isn't even all that bad (I mean, the drive will work, it'll just be bottlenecked) it's just that we can't verify if this answer is accurate at all because OP listed a combination that simply won't work at all. For all we know OP is sitting on a board that does have SATA III.

Comment: It seems like an attempt to create a computer out of some spare hardware. In any case, I maintain that the answer is accurate for the specified question.

Comment: @harrymc Why did you state _"...with SATA II (if it will even work"_? SATA3 is backwards compatible, just as SATA2 is backwards compatible.  The only thing that would occur is the drive would be locked to a max 300MB/s instead of its normal max of 520MB/s.  That being said, it's likely this speed difference may not even be noticed provided RAPID mode is enabled _(utilizes RAM at the bit level to enable 2.5GB/s+ transfer speeds for large file transfers)_.

Comment: @JW0914: Theoretically yes, but each device is different in hardware and firmware. I can't guarantee compatiblity so I play it safe.